# Space required on MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY is 0.0KB

Tags: nsis

I'm writing an installer for Windows application.  I'm using MUI for NSIS. One of the pages of the installer is Directory Page, where I have the "Space required" field. The problem is that the space required is always 0.0KB.

I was looking for some answers, but all I found was that space is calculated automatically. I wonder if there is some way to check which folder size this macro gets? Or any other ideas?

```
;Pages

; Installation
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE                "@CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_LICENSE@"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
Page custom pgAppLanguageCreate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what causes the problem.
In the "Installer Section" I used a function that copies all files.
Instead of calling it here, I just paste the entire function and now that works. It looks like you cant use "File" instruction in function because it doesn't add size to the required space this way. 
If you use it in section, it works perfectly.

```
; Installer Sections     
Section "install" Install 

    ${If} $instState != "1"
        Call deleteAllFiles
        Call deleteInfoFromRegistry
        Call deleteShortcut
    ${EndIf}


    SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"

    ; copy files
    File ${ICON}
    File "slicer_license"
    File /r "${INSTALL_FILE}\package\"
    ;File "README.txt" ;Readme file.
    Call createShortcut
    Call addInfoToRegistry
    Call setAppLanguageShortcut
    Call createLanguageFile

SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 1):

The size is automatically calculated by the `File` instructions **in** `Section`s plus any extra you add with `AddSize`.

If you are not happy with this calculation you can force a specific size in `.onInit` with `SectionSetSize`.